# UIImagePickerController hides cancel button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController which gets opened by pressing a button. Here is the code i use to open UIImagePickerController

```
- (BOOL)shouldStartPhotoLibraryPickerController {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] == NO
         && [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)) {
        return NO;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [cameraUI.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255 green:19/255 blue:18/255 alpha:1]];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]
        && [[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary] containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

    } else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]
               && [[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];

    } else {
        return NO;
    }

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    [Flurry logEvent:@"Picture Choosen"];
    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

The view opens fine for the first time. with no status bar and a cancel button as expected.But once any of the albums is selected the status bar shows up and when i navigate back to albums list view the status bar stays and the cancel button is no more there. This only happens in iOS 8. I don't have any issues on iOS 7. I also tested it on iOS 8.1 and it is still an issue. Is this a bug in the iOS or am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same issue i am facing . Have you got the solution ?

Comment: I also have the same problem. did you get the answer?

Comment: Please refer this answer if every case doesn't work stackoverflow.com/a/50490924/1201274

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
cameraPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext

Comment: Thank you but I still have that issue. Also I discovered something very weird is that if I go back by pressing the back button, the cancel button disappears but if i go back by swiping from the left edge of the phone, the cancel button stays.